# Populating an array from an input file

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I'm an extreme beginner with vb and coding in general and this is my first post on this site. I am running into a wall with a project I am working on. This is the smallest block of code in the project but all other functions will pull from the array I'm trying to populate. Essentially I need to populate an array with numbers representing the prices of DVDs from a .txt file. The .txt file is formatted as follows:

The Lord of the Rings, 10.50
Avatar, 5
Gangs of New York, 7.5
etc

Where 10.50 is the value I would want to assign to dblPrices(0). It is required to not change the format of the .txt file. So far, this is what I was using but when testing the output I'm getting back 0's:

```
    'Declare variables.
    Dim intCount As Integer = 0
    Dim strLine As String

    'Open the file for input.
    inFile = IO.File.OpenText("availableDVDs.txt")

    'Remove alpha characters from string, assign numeric values to array representing price.
    Do Until inFile.Peek = -1
        strLine = inFile.ReadLine.ToUpper.Replace("[A-Z]", "")
        strLine = strLine.Replace(" ", "")
        strLine = strLine.Replace(",", "")
        Double.TryParse(strLine, dblPrices(intCount))
        intCount += 1
    Loop
```

This is related to a school project so I'm not necessarily looking for someone to do my work for me, but perhaps point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Split on the comma, do the TryParse on the second element.

Comment: I tried that, in fact that was my first thought. However we are required to have Option Strict On so I get an implicit conversion error from "String" to "Char"

Comment: We can fix that if you show that code.

Comment: `dim values = strLine.Split(","c) dim value As Decimal = 0.0D If Decimal.TryParse(values(1), NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, value) Then dblPrices(intCount) = value end if`
. You should use a `List(Of Decimal)`. How do you know how many lines you'll find in that file? How did you set the dimension of the array?

Comment: We were allowed to hard code the array's dimension.

Comment: Although it would not cause the error you are getting, the code in your question will return unexpected results if the title contains and non-alphabetic characters other than a space or a comma. Jimi's suggestion is the way to go but that code will fail if the title contains a comma. Rather than `Decimal.TryParse(values(1)`, use `Decimal.TryParse(values(values.Length - 1))`.

Comment: "We were allowed to hard code the array's dimension." Yes, but how did you decide how big to make the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `List(Of T)` (The T stands for `Type`, like `Integer` or `String` or your own type) then you don't need to know the size in advance like an array. Also you don't need to keep track of indexes. You can just use the `.Add` method and the new item is put at the end of the list.

You can get a head start on getting the data out of the file by using `File.ReadAllLines` which will return an array of lines in the text file. Then you can just `.Split` each line on the "," (comma) and use the second element of the resulting array. The little c after the comma in double quotes tells the compiler that you mean this a Char which is the datatype that .Split is expecting.

I used a `Decimal` datatype instead of `Double`. When working with money it is safer to use to get the answer you expect.

In the second code sample I used an Interpolated sting indicated by the $ preceding the string. Notice that it is very similar to `String.Format` only the variable is inserted directly in the braces instead of a placeholder. This is available in Visual Studio 2015 and later.

The array method...

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim Lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("availableDVDs.txt")
    Dim Prices(Lines.Count - 1) As Decimal
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim price As Decimal
    For Each line In Lines
        Dim SplitOnComma = line.Split(","c)
        If Decimal.TryParse(SplitOnComma(1), price) Then
            Prices(index) = price
            index += 1
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Price for {0} is not valid.", SplitOnComma(0)))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The list method...

```
Private Sub UsingList()
    Dim Lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines("availableDVDs.txt")
    Dim Prices As New List(Of Decimal)
    Dim price As Decimal
    For Each line In Lines
        Dim SplitOnComma = line.Split(","c)
        If Decimal.TryParse(SplitOnComma(1), price) Then
            Prices.Add(price)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show($"Price for {SplitOnComma(0)} is not valid.")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

With Option Infer Off

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim Lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("availableDVDs.txt")
    Dim Prices(Lines.Count - 1) As Decimal
    Dim index As Integer
    Dim price As Decimal
    For Each line In Lines
        Dim SplitOnComma() As String = line.Split(","c)
        If Decimal.TryParse(SplitOnComma(1), price) Then
            Prices(index) = price
            index += 1
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Price for {0} is not valid.", SplitOnComma(0)))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have added code to my answer to cover Option Infer off. When you are allowed to turn it on you will see that the editor already knows the type so you don't need to add it.

Comment: Hi Mary, thank you for your reply. I am interesting in implementing the array method but I am getting a few errors. I am required to have Option Strict on, and I am getting multiple instances of the following error "Option Strict On disallows late binding". In addition, several instances of "Option Strict on requires all variable declarations to have an "As" statement. Finally, in each mention of "line" the error "line is not declared" comes up. Any advice?

Comment: I turned all options off just to test, and I get an unhandled exception:

System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Count' on type 'String()' not found.'

Comment: Change .Count to .Length

Comment: You need Option Explicit and Option Strict to keep you code clean. Turn those 2 ON.